# how can I pipe a powershell call command

Tags: powershell, pytest

I'm porting some pytest linux bash scripts to windows powershell.

Without the pipe stage at the end script runs fine. But I need a complete $outputlog for next stage parsing. Script runs fine and output to what is should to file in all examples but it hangs at the end. never continue without a ctr+c.

If I add a pipe to the end, the call never returns and hangs until I quit it. $outputlog is created fine:

```
&"$exe" -s --capture=no --log-cli-level=$loglevel \
--webhost=$testenv --durations=0 --tb=short .\tests --html=$testenv.html \
| Set-Content $outputlog
```

if I user Transcript, the $outputlog is empty except for the transcript header and footer:

```
Start-Transcript -Path $outputlog
&"$exe" -s --capture=no --log-cli-level=$loglevel \
--webhost=$testenv --durations=0 --tb=short .\tests \
--html=$testenv.html
Stop-Transcript
```

This one writes nothing to console but all to $outputlog, but it also hangs:

```
&"$exe" -s --capture=no --log-cli-level=$loglevel \
--webhost=$testenv --durations=0 --tb=short .\tests \
--html=$testenv.html > $outputlog 2>&1
```

[pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.1.2/):  have its own capturing control the `-s --capture=no` which should mean no capturing, changing those variables did not help anything

Comment: Have you tried `& $exe ... | Out-File $outputlog`?

Comment: Perhaps the exe is "hanging" because it's waiting for input? Try ```"`n" | & $exe ... | Set-Content ...```

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, `$exe` + params executes and output is in `$outputfile` but it still hangs

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks, It still hangs, script executes fine and capture is witten to file but it no not return. I might be a capturing lock in pytest, since it captures everything

Comment: Curious if this has something to do with the arguments passed to the exe and `&`. Can you try wrapping your `&` argument like so? `& { "$exe" -s ... }`?

Comment: Can you give more info about $exe? Link to the docs?

Comment: @zett42 added link tp pytest, it is the premier test-framework used with python, but it has lots of complex parameters, so it might be something there

Comment: @JeremyFortune I get a parse error on the first parameter '-s' if I try adding curlies, but I will try to create a `invoke-Expression` block instead of `&` single line directly.

Comment: If you form a ScriptBlock, you can stop pwsh from parsing remaining arguments with `--%`, which may solve this parsing problem and let you keep Invoke-Command.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I found piping to Out-File blocks closing the file until all processes started in the scriptblock has been terminated.

I use environment variables to control settings and one option I use during development is to keep the webdriver and webbrowser open, so I can jump in and fix in case of error.

If I close all processes started in scriptblock it completes. This is originally a port from linux where this is no problem whatsoever.

So my solution is to set the variables explicitly to a non blocking condition.

```
if ( -not (Test-Path "$($pwd)\win\")) {
   $ENV:PATH+=";" + $pwd + "\win\"
}
$ENV:WEBDRIVER='ChromeHeadless'
$ENV:SCREENSHOT=1
$ENV:WEBDRIVER_LANG='en'
if (Test-Path env:WEBDRIVER_OPEN) {
   # if set will block outfile due to open process in $cmd
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('WEBDRIVER_OPEN', $null, 'User')
}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
   Invoke-Expression $cmd | Out-File -NoClobber -FilePath $outputlog
}
```

All this for the summary line of pytest, which is used to define status of tests:

```
Get-Content -Path .\output.log -tail 1 
======================== 3 passed in 62.18s (0:01:02) =========================
```

Thanks for all the valuable input.